# Reliably accessing public Wi-Fi "Agreement" page on Android

Tags: wi-fi, captive-portal

This has probably been addressed elsewhere, but I can't find it, so I will risk the ire of the community by asking it here.

When I connect to public Wi-Fi on my Android phone (version 6.0.1 at the moment), it pops open Chrome so I can hit “agree” or whatever the public Wi-Fi provider asks me to hit before giving proper internet access. Chrome always tries to bring up https://www.google.com, which, of course, doesn't redirect properly because it's http**s**. So I manually type in hp.com since it's quick to type and doesn't redirect to https. Then whatever captive portal software is running can “catch” it and redirect me to the agreement page.

My question is: how to make Chrome (or Android) go somewhere else besides https://www.google.com? I assumed it was my home page configuration in Chrome, but it's not.

In case it's relevant, I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S5.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a home screen shortcut that will do what you want. First bookmark your “hp.com”. I use “this.com. Then go to your bookmarks and long press the one you want. At the bottom of the pop up menu should be the option to “Add to Home Screen”. Select that.

Now, when you need to sign in on public Wi-Fi, just start your browser from the shortcut on your home screen. For me… Works every time!